# Where is the menu bar in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows XP, most programs used to have menu bars. One common feature of menu bars was a **Tools** menu. How can I get menu bars back in Windows 7 Pro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but try this:

Open Computer, then click Organize>Layout>Menu bar. That will bring it back for you.

[image]

Comment: Its almost like MS did not want users to find it, so they buried it.

Comment: @Moab I always turn it back on.

Answer (score 4):

You can bring the menu bar up at any time by hitting the Alt key.  This also works in other applications that hide the menu bar by default, such as Firefox 4+, Windows Media Player, and others.  Most (if not all) have an option to always show the menu bar.

As KCotreau said, `Organize -> Layout -> Menu bar` will show it in Windows Explorer.

Comment: +1 I could have also mentioned the ALT key.